# Javascript make variable from an array of characters

Tags: javascript

How you can make a variable from an array of characters in Javascript.

```
chars = ["a","b","c","d"];
chars[1],chars[0],chars[2] = "Hellow world";
alert(bac); // Hellow world
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that? Variable/dynamic variables are usually considered bad coding practice. Why not use a map instead?

Comment: You can't. You can set properties on an object, though. (You could `eval`, I suppose, but please don't.)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: You can make a key value pair on an object, not an actual variable but part of an object.  An actual variable cannot be dynamically generated.

Comment: @FelixKling i don't know what map means but if it can do what i'm looking for please show me how.

Comment: Heh, you could use the `window` object to create a global variable like that... assuming we're in a browser. But what is the context? Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @DaveNewton i'm using this for obfuscation so any solution who makes the code above to work  is acceptable

Comment: please if someone know how to make the code work write the code, if i know how to do it using window or eval or anything else i wouldn't ask this question

Comment: A map is a data structure that allows you to associate values with labels, at runtime. You can use objects as maps (e.g. `var things = {}; things.foo = value;`) or the `Map` class (e.g. `var things = new Map(); things.set('foo', value);` ).

Comment: The problem is that you want to do something that isn't a good idea. So the question is why you want to do so we can suggest a better solution. *"i'm using this for obfuscation"* Why don't you use an existing tool for obfuscating your code?

Comment: @FelixKling i want to make a hidden variable so at the end of the code you will see just " alert(abc) " but if you search for that variable in javascript code you will not find it .

Comment: Related: [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530/218196)

Comment: *"but if you search for that variable in javascript code you will not find it"* - Who do you think will be searching through your code? And why?

Comment: This is almost completely non-obfuscated. Use an obfuscater.

Comment: @nnnnnn hackers haha, just kidding.it's for a streaming site . they take the streaming link and they put it on thier website. it's just a layer of protection again thoes who doesn't know anything about coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is **absolutely not** a good practice. Only do it for fun. No professional work uses code like this.

That said:

```
chars = ['a', 'b', 'c']
eval("window." + chars.join('') + " = 'Hello World'")
alert(abc)
```

Yep.

Comment: No reason to use `eval` here, you can just use `[]` notation.

Comment: Haha true. I wonder why I thought of using `eval`. Well, @Arvind got it simpler

Answer (score 3):

There is no need for `eval` or `map`:

```js
var chars = ["a", "b", "c", "d"];
window[chars[1] + chars[0] + chars[2]] = "Hellow world";
console.log(bac); // Hellow world
```

Comment: That's a property on an object, which is what I said, no?